# Java.lang.NumberFormatException when trying to read in a file, so I can use the data with my objects

Tags: java, arrays, csv, object, arraylist

I keep getting this error when I'm trying to read in a file and add the data to my objects. Can someone please help me? Here is the error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "N64"
at java.base/java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:67)
at java.base/java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:668)
at java.base/java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:786)
at FinalProjectTests.main(FinalProjectTests.java:34)
```

Here are my objects. Also at the bottom I have setters and getters below the code as well as a `toString()` method generated by Eclipse:

[image]

Here is my code that is trying to read in a file and add the data to my objects:

```java
public class FinalProjectTests {

    //create an arraylist so the objects can be used through them
    public static ArrayList<FinalProjectRecord> record = new ArrayList<FinalProjectRecord>();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = null;
        try {
            input = new Scanner(new File("Video Games Sales.csv"));
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            System.out.println("file not found");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }//end try

        //skips the title columns in our data file
        input.nextLine();
        while(input.hasNext()) {
            String [] columns = input.nextLine().split(",");
            record.add(new FinalProjectRecord(Integer.parseInt(columns[0]),
                                              columns[1],
                                              columns[2],
                                              Integer.parseInt(columns[3]),
                                              columns[4],
                                              columns[5],
                                              Double.parseDouble(columns[6]),
                                              Double.parseDouble(columns[7]),
                                              Double.parseDouble(columns[8]),
                                              Double.parseDouble(columns[9]),
                                              Double.parseDouble(columns[10]),
                                              Double.parseDouble(columns[11])));
        }//end while
        for(FinalProjectRecord r: record)
            System.out.println(r);
    }//end main
}//end class
```

Here is a snippet of the data I am trying to read in:

[image]

Edit: I got the data from *data.world*.

Comment: check order of Column in CSV and convert to number in your code: Integer.parseInt, Double.parseDouble

Comment: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "N64" -- it is getting "N64" to convert into number... but "N" makes N64 unable to convert. the data u have posted as picture Nappears to be excel sheet? if so search "N64" in sheet and correct accordingly

Comment: Please never post images of text. They are not searchable, we cannot copy-paste... Always copy-paste the text and format it properly.
If you'd done that right, we'd perhaps be able to help examining the source data

Comment: So you're trying to parse a CSV file, and a field that you think is numeric isn't. I suspect that one of your game titles has a `,` comma in it, so your split is shifting all of your columns. You should probably use a CSV library. Can you paste some of the raw text from the csv file? (Maybe data.world doesn't allow you to do that.)

Comment: If you can, [edit] your question and post the entire contents of file _Video Games Sales.csv_ as text and not as a screen shot of [Microsoft] Excel. Open the file in an editor, like `Notepad`, rather than using the default application (which is Excel) and simply copy/paste the file contents. Alternatively, provide a link to the file or explain how to obtain it from [data.world](https://data.world/) As in @matt [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74455767/java-lang-numberformatexception-when-trying-to-read-in-a-file-so-i-can-use-the#comment131441782_74455767) the problem's in the file

Answer (score 0):

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input **string: "N64"**
Exception is thrown because of "**N**64".(**Integer.ParseInt or Double.ParseDouble in your code)**  The image you have posted as data, appears its is from EXCEL Sheet, if so, please search for "N64" and check whether it is correct in that column?

Answer (score 0):

You should really use a library for parsing csv files, this is an example using [commons-csv](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-csv/)

Here is my hastily made csv file.

```
'object','value'
'red', 255
'blue', 100
'green, yellow', 50
```

This simple program will parse it.

```
import org.apache.commons.csv.CSVParser;
import org.apache.commons.csv.CSVFormat;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;

public class CsvReading{
    
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
        CSVParser parsing = CSVParser.parse(
                                  Paths.get("junk.csv"), 
                                  StandardCharsets.UTF_8, 
                                  CSVFormat.DEFAULT
        );
        System.out.println(parsing.getHeaderNames());
        System.out.println(parsing.getRecords());
    }
    
}
```

That will give an output with no headers, and 4 records.

> []

> [CSVRecord [comment='null', recordNumber=1, values=['object', 'value']], CSVRecord [comment='null', recordNumber=2, values=['red',  255]], CSVRecord [comment='null', recordNumber=3, values=['blue',  100]], CSVRecord [comment='null', recordNumber=4, values=['green,  yellow',  50]]]

You can see the last record has two elements, `'green, yellow'` and 50. If we were to use `String.split(",")` then yellow and green would be incorrectly split. This library is very easy to use, I just downloaded the jar file and run the program with.

```
java -cp commons-csv-1.9.0.jar CsvReading.java
```